# Подходящая библиотека C++ для написания сервера

Tags: c++

Решил изучать сетевое программирование на *C++*, знания языка как такового есть. Кроме него есть опыт программирования на *C#* и связанных с веб-разработкой языков и технологий (*html*, *css*, *js*, *ajax*, *asp.net*).

Скорее просто для себя хочу писать приложения клиент-сервер, что-то вроде бот-нета )) Посоветуйте, с какой библиотеки лучше начать чтобы был самый маленький размер сервера и с какими продолжать, например *WinAPI*, *WinSock* и т.д.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если пишите под Windows платформу, то в winsock2.h есть все что нужно, будет низкоуровнево, но малый вес обсепечен.

Второй вариант Boost, но придется тянуть за собой не маленькую библиотеку.